# Как заставить работать авторизацию через mail.ru на основном домене и на поддоменах?

Tags: oauth, mail.ru

Делаю авторизацию через mail.ru на сайте. Один и тот же проект но разные его модули находятся на адресах example.com, subdomain.example.com, subdomain2.example.com. Но в настройках приложения в mail.ru я могу указать только один адрес сайта и только один адрес файла reciever.html
И таким образом авторизация работает только на одном из доменов, который я указываю в настройках. Как мне заставить авторизацию работать на всех трех доменах?